# Subclassing UICollectionViewLayout with cached UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to understand how `UICollectionViewLayout` works and found this sample code.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts

In the sample code(and all other examples I could find), it has `cachedLayoutAttributes` object and calculates all items' layout in `prepare()`.

I found 2 issues for this pattern.

One is if the number of data source is big enough, calculating everything in the `prepare()` method will take time(and it will be recalculated whenever collectionView's layout changes), so it doesn't look very efficient.

The other issue is that there is no chance `layoutAttributesForItem` or `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView` get called. Only `layoutAttributesForElements` gets called and it seems it is sufficient enough to layout cells/supplementary views.

I read documentations but it only says the methods must be override. My best guess is that I should use override those methods to return an appropriate `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` and call them from `layoutAttributesForElements`. However this `layoutAttributesForElements` gets called whenever user scrolls UICollectionView, so it also seems not very efficient.

I want to know what is the case `layoutAttributesForItem` and `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView` get called, and what/when/where is the best way/place/time to calculate `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` if the number of data source is huge.

*Update*

Thanks for the comment. However it seems like it's about optimization in invalidation cycle.

> Layout objects that are designed to support invalidation contexts can use the information in a UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext object to optimize their behavior during the invalidation cycle.

Which means the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` are already set and invalidate only necessary part, right?

So, where should I calculate `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the first time? Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Read the UICollectionViewLayout docs, esp. the section "Optimizing Layout Performance Using Invalidation Contexts". There are a number of useful WWDC videos on this topic too, such as WWDC 2014 session 226.

Comment: Also session 232 from the same year.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: Well obviously a minimal implementation would be to perform the calculation and caching only when you get the request for layout attributes for items in rect. Those are all the items that need to appear on screen initially. However you have to perform _some_ overall initial calculation because the first big question is how big the content view needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One is if the number of data source is big enough, calculating everything in the `prepare()` method will take time(and it will be recalculated whenever collectionView's layout changes), so it doesn't look very efficient.

Yeah, it doesn't look very efficient. It's your job to make `prepare()` calculations as efficient as possible.

For example: calculate only a portion of attributes and calculate more when scroll changed its position using [`shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617781-shouldinvalidatelayout). But be careful with this method because it might invalidate the layout on every pixel scroll.

`prepare()` method is not called just for fun, it informs you that something is changed and recalculation is required! But the information about changes is hard to get. You can check how [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit) gets information about changes before prepare: [link](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Source/IGListCollectionViewLayout.mm).

> The other issue is that there is no chance `layoutAttributesForItem` or `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView` get called. Only `layoutAttributesForElements` gets called and it seems it is sufficient enough to layout cells/supplementary views.

`layoutAttributesForElements(in:)` is called first because the collection doesn't know about the order of your cells and supplementary views. So it asks for all attributes in the specified rectangle. Try to insert/move/delete/reload cells, I believe `layoutAttributesForItem(at:)` might be called. Or maybe not. But you should not worry about it because you already have cache of attributes.

Since you cache attributes `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)` should be efficient enough and will look something like this:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return attributes
        .reduce(into: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes](), { $0 += $1.filter({ $0.frame.intersects(rect) }) })
}
```

I personally suggest to look inside some difficult open-source layout. You will get much more information about the `UICollectionViewLayout` compared to information from any simple sample project.